# Split the string based on given delimeter ignoring double quted part

Tags: java, string, csv, split, delimiter

I need to split a string to sub strings based on delimeter.
Here is a code :

```
String[] fields = line.split(Pattern.quote(CSV_DELIMITER)); //CSV_DELIMITER=","
```

I get the following line "1234, "dfd, ddss", 35345"
The expectection was is that the result will have 3 fields : 1234, "dfd, ddss", 35345, But it has 4: 1234, dfd, ddss, 35345
How can I solve that? (The content in double quotes should not be splitted)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the CSVParser from Apache Commons.

It can handle fields containing the delimiter (and much more):

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/

```
CSVFormat.withDelimiter(',').withQuote('"')
```

`CSVFormat.EXCEL`
     would be a shortcut for:

```
 CSVFormat
 .withDelimiter(',')
 .withQuote('"')
 .withRecordSeparator("\r\n")
 .withIgnoreEmptyLines(false)
 .withAllowMissingColumnNames(true)
```